# Java convert object into abstract object

Tags: java, objectmapper

I am using SpringBoot with Java 1.8.

I have two objects that I would like to deep copy one to the other.

**Basic structure**

```
QuoteRequestDTO -> TravelRequirementDTO -> ItineraryDTO -> ServiceDTO
```

and

```
QuoteRequest -> TravelRequirement -> Itinerary -> Service
```

note: the Entity objects come from an external library I cannot change.  I can change the DTO objects.

For  example, I want to copy a `DTO` to an `Entity`.

**DTO**

```
public class QuoteRequestDTO {    
    protected TravelRequirementDTO travel;
    ...
```

and

```
public class TravelRequirementDTO {
    protected ItineraryDTO required;
    ...
```

and

```
public class ItineraryDTO extends PayableDTO {
    protected List<ServiceDTO> service;
    ...
```

and

```
public class ServiceDTO extends PayableDTO {
    ...
```

**Entity**

```
public class QuoteRequest {
    protected TravelRequirement travel;
    ...
```

and

```
public class TravelRequirement implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected Itinerary required;
    ...
```

and

```
public class Itinerary extends Payable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected List<Service> service;
    ...
```

and

```
public abstract class Service extends Payable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ...
```

**Copy Utility**

I have tried the following:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class CopyUtils {

    public static <T>T deepCopy(Object sourceObject, T targetObject) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = getJacksonObjectMapper();
        T targetBean = (T) mapper.convertValue(sourceObject, targetObject.getClass());
        return targetBean;
    }

    private static ObjectMapper getJacksonObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
        objectMapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public void getQuote(QuoteRequestDTO quoteRequestDTO) {
    QuoteRequest quoteRequest = new QuoteRequest();
    quoteRequest = CopyUtils.deepCopy(quoteRequestDTO, quoteRequest);
```

**Error**

It gets the following error:

> Cannot construct instance of `com.mycompany.transit._2008a.Service`
> (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either
> need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or
> contain additional type information  at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset:
> #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: com.mycompany.transit._2008a.availability.QuoteRequest["travel"]->com.mycompany.transit._2008a.TravelRequirement["required"]->com.mycompany.transit._2008a.Itinerary["service"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

When I change the `ServiceDTO` to be an **abstract** class:

```
public abstract class ServiceDTO extends PayableDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

It get the following error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
> construct instance of `com.mycompany.restosgi.dto.transit.ServiceDTO`
> (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either
> need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or
> contain additional type information  at [Source:
> (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line:
> 13, column: 13] (through reference chain:
> com.mycompany.restosgi.dto.transit.availability.QuoteRequestDTO["travel"]->com.mycompany.restosgi.dto.transit.TravelRequirementDTO["required"]->com.mycompany.restosgi.dto.transit.ItineraryDTO["service"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

**Question**

Is there a way I can write a generic utility method to deep copy objects to another object that has abstract objects?

**Possible solution**

Is there a way to add a converter that creates the relevant concrete class (implementation)?

The `Service` needs to be an implementation, for example a `TransitService`.

e.g.

```
public class TransitService extends Service implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

**Possible Solution**

As per the advise from Delta George below, I am trying the following:

```
public class ItineraryDTO extends PayableDTO {
    protected List<ServiceDTO> service;

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void serService(String key, ArrayNode array) {
        service = new ArrayList<>();
        array.forEach(json -> service.add(toService(json)));
    }

    private ServiceDTO toService(JsonNode json) {
        if (json.has("some unique property of flight")) {
            return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(json, FlightDTO.class);
        } else if (json.has("some unique property of transit")) {
            return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(json, TransitServiceDTO.class);
        } else return null;
    }

    ...
```

However, I cannot get it to invoke the `serService` method.  I think I need to add some Spring config to do so?

Also, if I make the `ServiceDTO` abstract, it get the following error.

```
public abstract class ServiceDTO extends PayableDTO {
```

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
> construct instance of `com.clubtravel.restosgi.dto.transit.ServiceDTO`
> (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either
> need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or
> contain additional type information  at [Source:
> (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line:
> 13, column: 13] (through reference chain:
> com.clubtravel.restosgi.dto.transit.availability.QuoteRequestDTO["travel"]->com.clubtravel.restosgi.dto.transit.TravelRequirementDTO["required"]->com.clubtravel.restosgi.dto.transit.ItineraryDTO["service"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.2.1.jar:2.13.2.1]

Comment: How would you convert a `List<ServiceDTO>` into a `List<Service>`?

Comment: I think my problem is I need to create the specific implementation of `Service`. So I don't think I can have a generic `deepCopy` method.

Comment: you could, but you need a way to select which (concrete) subclass of `Service` to use (and instanciate) to copy some element of the source list (`ServiceDTO` or some subclass).

Comment: If, for each concrete subclass of `Service` you had a corresponding subclass of `ServiceDTO`, then you would need to register a converter for each of these subclasses.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like a good solution that allows it to keep a generic method with the required flexibility. I am not sure how to create a converter, but am looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concept implementation using Jackson's @JsonAnySetter to intercept incoming objects as an array of JSON trees and convert each to a concrete POJO based on the structure of each object:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
static abstract class Person {
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
static class PersonA extends Person {
    String a;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
static class PersonB extends Person {
    String b;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
static class People {
    List<Person> team;

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setTeam(String key, ArrayNode array) {
        team = new ArrayList<>();
        array.forEach(json -> team.add(toPerson(json)));
    }

    private Person toPerson(JsonNode json) {
        if (json.has("a")) {
            return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(json, PersonA.class);
        } else if (json.has("b")) {
            return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(json, PersonB.class);
        } else return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String json = "{\"team\": [{\"a\": 123}, {\"b\": 45}]}";

    People people = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, People.class);
    System.out.println(people);

    // Prints: People(team=[PersonA(a=123), PersonB(b=45)])
}

// back to the OP's data model

public static class QuoteRequest {
    protected TravelRequirement travel;

    public TravelRequirement getTravel() {
        return travel;
    }

    public void setTravel(TravelRequirement travel) {
        this.travel = travel;
    }
}

public static class TravelRequirement implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected Itinerary required;

    public Itinerary getRequired() {
        return required;
    }

    public void setRequired(Itinerary required) {
        this.required = required;
    }
}

public static class Itinerary extends Payable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected List<Service> service;

    public void service(List<Service> service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getService() {
        return Map.of("service", service);
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setService(String key, ArrayNode array) {
        service = new ArrayList<>();
        array.forEach(json -> service.add(toService(json)));
    }

    private Service toService(JsonNode json) {
        return getJacksonObjectMapper().convertValue(json, TransitService.class);
    }
}

public static abstract class Service extends Payable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}

public static class TransitService extends Service implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}

public static class Payable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}

private static ObjectMapper getJacksonObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
    objectMapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    return objectMapper;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    QuoteRequest qr = new QuoteRequest();
    TravelRequirement tr = new TravelRequirement();
    Itinerary i = new Itinerary();
    i.service(List.of(new TransitService()));
    tr.setRequired(i);
    qr.setTravel(tr);

    ObjectMapper mapper = getJacksonObjectMapper();
    QuoteRequest qr2 = mapper.convertValue(qr, QuoteRequest.class);
    System.out.println(qr2);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.  I am struggling to convert this solution to my particular needs.   If I manage to, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Added to the answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this looks like it will work. I am just struggling to get it to call the `@JsonAnySetter  public void serService` method.  (I have added a more detailed explanation to the original question).

Comment: Please see updated answer with a working example on how to implement Itinerary. The example converts to the same class and not to a DTO class but it shows the concept. You can not have a regular getter when you have @JsonAnySetter. Regular getter will block any setter.